# How does Laravel interally create certain parts of the verification email?

Tags: laravel, hash, email-verification

When creating a verification email with Laravel this is how the link can end up looking:

.../verify/1/3f4f10efdbac36ec6892bb3572ac6683ff663ad8?expires=1641580767&signature=babf2d50deb610a551d0477132193abb595d8664b56a9074c38f5b3789933ad

1. After the "verify/1/" there seems to be some hash of length 40.
2. The last query parameter "signature" has a hash of length 60.

My questions are: How are these hashes created? Which hash function is used and what is the input string? Also what is the purpose of those parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- The first part after the `verify/1/` is the [sha1](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) of the registered user email.
We use this to make sure we validate the same email we have in the db and the one the user registered with.

2- The last part of the url is a [sha256](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2#SHA-256) signature to make sure the url is not altered by a malicious user. Any modification to the url will make the signature fails. Note that the signature is checked with the [Laravel Signed middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/urls#validating-signed-route-requests)

So it is basically security measures to prevent malicious user.
For more informations:
The generated link will be in the notification class here: `src/Illuminate/Auth/Notifications/VerifyEmail.php`

Once the user clicked the link, it will be processed and checked in the file below: `vendor/laravel/ui/auth-backend/VerifiesEmails.php`